# is the Mollom free plan suitable for a site with 300 hits p/m?

Tags: advertising

I'm looking for the right module to prevent spam. So far I think that the best mollom but I don't fully understand if it is free.

I their website: www.mollom.com they says that `Mollom Free is our most basic spam filtering service, which we make available for free to sites with limited post volumes.`

but also that the free plan is for `Personal blog`.

Let say I can implement it in a restaurant website which get 300 visits a month. Can I use the free plan?

Comment: You'll have to read the features and decide for yourself.  The *actual* question here ("is the Mollom free plan suitable for a site with 300 hits p/m") is both off-topic and not contructive for DA I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe is off-topic, but I think it could be useful for someone else. I will close it anyway.

Comment: For the record: **Mollom** has been discontinued and the question is now irrelevant. Suggesting deletion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use it on a website with 300 visits a month. However it will only allow 50 correct CAPTCHAs in a day but will stop unlimited spam posts.

Answer (score 1):

Mollom **module** for Drupal is free. Mollom **service** is another story, and you need to ask their customer support about it.